# Equivalent of Vlookup for Stata

Tags: stata

I have two data sets, one where I have some 'raw' data and the other one containing 'results' of analysis of this 'raw' data.

I would like to find a way to operate an Excel equivalent `vlookup()` to retrieved the analysed data in the raw data.

My data set looks like as follows:

```
RAW

John 12
Tim 13 
Steve 25 
Amy 47

ANALYSED

John Yes
Steve No
Tim Maybe
```

After the `vlookup`, my data would look like this:

```
John 12 Yes
Tim 13 Maybe
Steve 25 No
Amy 47 NA
```

I haven't been very successful in finding a similar command on Stata - any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: No vlookup is necessary here, but Kevin Crow wrote a command that you can find with `search vlookup`.

Comment: It seems to me that this `vlookup` command only works with one data set - and I have two datasets, am I wrong?

Comment: It could be used after the merge, if you had something more involved to vlookup. For this example, only a merge is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Please read about providing good examples at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve There is no attempt at code in your question and the sample data require surgery before they can be read into Stata.

I would not call this vlookup, just a basic `merge`.

```
clear 
input str5 name value 
"John" 12
"Tim" 13 
"Steve" 25 
"Amy" 47
end 
save raw, replace  


clear 
input str5 (name whatever) 
"John" "Yes"
"Steve" "No"
"Tim" "Maybe" 
end 


merge 1:1 name using raw 
list 

     +-------------------------------------------+
     |  name   whatever   value           _merge |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. |  John        Yes      12      matched (3) |
  2. | Steve         No      25      matched (3) |
  3. |   Tim      Maybe      13      matched (3) |
  4. |   Amy                 47   using only (2) |
     +-------------------------------------------+
```

What resources are you scanning? The menu choices `Data > Combine datasets > Merge two datasets` point to `merge`, although that is easier to point out if you know the answer.